# NTFS shared drive blanked after booting to Windows on a dual boot setup (Fedora/Windows 10)

Tags: linux, windows, ntfs

I've been setting up my laptop for dual booting between Windows 10 and Fedora (more precisely, Nobara) on a SSD. I also have a HDD for files so I decided to format it as NTFS in order to share it between both OS. After a few days of not using Windows I booted into it in order to configure a gamepad and since I've just barely made any changes to my Windows partition I decided to check how well it could read the files of the NTFS data drive.

The problem: It appears as a blank drive.

I had fast boot enabled (which I shouldn't) and I don't remember opening up the drive on Windows before. So it was a rookie mistake and I have some of my files backed up. The thing is, after booting into Nobara, the files were gone but the space used is marked as **if the files were there**. I know this is how files work but I'd love to know how to recover the whole drive. I'm planning to use Testdisk but maybe there's an easier solution?

I've tried looking on the hidden files of the data drive. It's named the same as before so I haven't tried anything else hoping the whole drive is recoverable as a whole.